# how to get value of evaluate in Jelly

Tags: servicenow, jelly

I am fresh to use Servicenow glides.
I followed the guide and wrote a piece of jelly file like below,

```
<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form" xmlns:c="/lib/credentials" xmlns:s="/lib/samples">
    <g:evaluate var="jvar_the_output" object="true" jelly="true">
        var outPuts = 'helloworld';
        outPuts;
    </g:evaluate>
    <h1>--${jvar_the_output}--</h1>

</j:jelly>
```

I am thinking to print the big helloworld on the page, but I see below contents print on page directly.

**var outPuts = 'helloworld';outPuts;**

**----**

Can someone help to check what is the problem?

Comment: Where are you entering this at, as a UI Page or somewhere else? I've tried your code as the HTML in a UI Page and it outputs **--helloworld--**

Comment: @Kirk I put this into my Jenkins plugin index.jelly, the content should display when i open the jenkins job configure page.